# How to run python script from C# code by using command

Tags: python, c#, asp.net-core, ironpython, scriptengine

I have a script file(run_edr.py) in my local machine and when I run it by using "cmd" and the following command then the script works perfectly. The script takes fewer parameters, the first parameter is an input document folder path and the second parameter is the output folder path to store the output documents.

my python command,

```
python run_edr.py -input_path "C:\Users\aslamm5165\Downloads\EDRCODE_ArgParser\files\EDR" -output_path "C:\Users\aslamm5165\Downloads\test" -site_name "a" -site_address "b" -site_city "c" -site_county "d" -site_state "e" -site_type "1"
```

I have tried like below, but not working, where Did I go wrong?

```
ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
        ScriptRuntime runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);
        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"C:\Users\aslamm5165\Downloads\EDRCODE_ArgParser\run_edr.py");
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
        List<String> argv = new List<String>();
        //Do some stuff and fill argv
        argv.Add("python"+@" C:\Users\aslamm5165\Downloads\EDRCODE_ArgParser\run_edr.py -input_path" + @"C:\Users\aslamm5165\Downloads\EDRCODE_ArgParser\files\EDR");
        argv.Add("-output_path"+ @"C:\Users\aslamm5165\Downloads\test");
        argv.Add("-site_name 'a' -site_address 'b' -site_city 'c' -site_county 'd' -site_state 'e' -site_type '1'");
        engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);
        source.Execute(scope);
```

I have tried with the system process as well as shown below, no error in the code, but the script is not getting executed. So I don't know what is the correct way of doing this but I want to start my script from my .Net Core application.

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();            
        start.FileName = @"cmd.exe";            
        start.Arguments = string.Format("python run_edr.py -input_path {0} -output_path {1}  -site_name 'a' -site_address 'b' -site_city 'c' -site_county 'd' -site_state 'e' -site_type '1'", @"C:\Users\aslamm5165\Downloads\EDRCODE_ArgParser\files\EDR", @"C:\Users\aslamm5165\Downloads\test");
        start.UseShellExecute = true;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(start);
```

Comment: There are spaces missing in your arg string: `"-output_path"+ @"C:\...`. This happend in a couple places. Generally the arg strings you are generating look very different from the one you gave as a working example. Try to generate and print the arg string with `System.Console.WriteLine()` and then compare.

Comment: in the first approach or second one?

Comment: Tried but same error that syntax is invalid.

Comment: I'd stick with the first approach for now. What error are you referring to?

Comment: it says only "Syntax Error"

Comment: When a lengthy command gives an unhelpful response ("syntax error"), the best approach is to "start simple', then work up to the command you really want. First get it to work with the simplest python command you can. A trivial script with no parameters. That may seem useless,  but if you can get it to run without syntax error, then you have made progress. Then start adding to it. Perhaps an output parameter but no input parameter. At some point, the syntax error will return. Easier to figure out what change caused it.

Comment: Dear would you share the python script to help me reprouce the isuue.

Comment: I can not share the file as it's confidential. What you want to know? can I share the def function parameters?

Comment: @toolmarketstev I have tried with simple script and that's working ,

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar running `Python` scripts in `.NET Core 3.1` problem by changing the executable file from `cmd.exe` or `/bin/bash` in Linux to a batch script (Windows) or shell script (Linux) file. Here's my approach:

**1**, for `Windows` OS, create a `run.bat` file which include the `python.exe` and the `%*` to pass all arguments to it:

```
C:\YOUR_PYTHON_PATH\python.exe %*
```

**2**, for `LInux` OS, create a `run.sh` file to execute python with arguments:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python3 "$@"
```

**3**, use `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` (your second approach):

```
string fileName = null;
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    fileName = "path_to_bat/run.bat"
}
else
{
    fileName = "path_to_bat/run.sh"
}

ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = fileName,
    Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", script, args),
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
using Process process = Process.Start(start);
```

the .NET code is same to Windows except the `FileName` should be the shell script's name with path.